# How to make a Luigi task generate an in-memory list as target

Tags: python, etl, luigi

I'm trying to write an etl pipeline using [luigi](http://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html). As far as I understand from the documentation a task in luigi can generate a target that can be either some type of file storage or a database. To decrese the processing time I would like to have as an output an in-memory list. Is this possible? Do I have to create a custom target?

Comment: Related to question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42515463/passing-python-objects-between-tasks-in-luigi, which some useful looking answers

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found out I can use a MockFile as a target. A good example:

http://gouthamanbalaraman.com/blog/building-luigi-task-pipeline.html

Comment: the author noted that: "I use the MockFile here just as a way to see the results on the console. This is usually a good testing tool, though I am not sure if it is production ready approach." So have you tried MockFile for (semi-)production pipelines? Is it right way for in-memory pipelining?